# Class of functions whose integral behaves as an exponential function.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis

> I'm looking for increasing functions $f:\mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}^+$ satisfying $\int_1^n f(x)dx \to \infty$, as $n\to \infty$, but with the property that for all $a>1,$
> $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty}
>  \frac{\left(\int_1^n f(x)^{a}dx\right)^{1/a}}{\int_1^n f(x)dx} \to \mathrm{constant} >0.
> $$

Clearly one example is $f(x)=e^x$, but what I'm interested in is if there are other functions that grow more slowly than $e^x$ and satisfy this property. $e^x$ satisfies that $(\int_1^n f(x)dx)/f(n) \to Constant$, i.e. the integral is basically captured by the value of the function at $n$. For the purpose of a counterexample I wish to construct, I was hoping there would be an example where the property holds, but $(\int_1^n f(x)dx)/f(n) \to \infty$.

Comment: Just as a very stupid counterexample: Take $f(x) = e^x$ on $\Bbb{R}^+ \setminus \Bbb{N}$ and $f(x) = 0$ on $\Bbb{N}$ :P It should even be possible to make this continuous, by modifying $f$ on sufficiently small regions around each $n \in \Bbb{N}$, shrinking the regions as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @PhoemueX Can you explain why this is a counterexample? If you remove a countable set of points from the reals, doesn't the Lebesgue integral converge to the same value, since that set of points has zero measure?

Comment: @DinosaurEgg: Sorry for the confusion. I meant this as a example satisfying the desired property but also $\int_1^n f(x) dx / f(n) \to \infty$. Also, one should of course take $f(x) = 1$ on $\Bbb{N}$ and not $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: Good point @PhoemueX, that example works, but misses what I was trying to go for. I've added the further restriction that the function should be increasing. Ideally the example would also work for discrete sums too, i.e. $\left(\sum_{j=1}^n f(j)^a \right)^{1/a} / \left(\sum_{j=1}^n f(j)\right) \to Constant>0$, but $\left(\sum_{j=1}^n f(j)\right) / f(n) \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No function as you would like does exist. To see this, note that your desired property $\int_1^n f(x) dx / f(n) \to \infty$ implies $f(n) / \int_1^n f(x) dx \to 0$. Therefore, since $f$ is increasing,
$$
\frac{(\int_1^n f(x)^a dx)^{1/a}}{\int_1^n f(x) dx}
= \bigg(
    \frac{\int_1^n f(x)^a dx}{(\int_1^n f(x) dx)^{a}}
  \bigg)^{1/a}
\leq \bigg(
    \frac{\int_1^n f(x) dx \cdot (f(n))^{a-1}}{\int_1^n f(x) dx \cdot (\int_1^n f(x) dx)^{a-1}}
  \bigg)^{1/a}
\xrightarrow{} 0,
$$
contradicting the convergence you would like.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks all! Do you think that the only functions that satisfy this property are exponential functions?

Comment: @LostStatistician: Well, maybe "up to 'small' changes". What you can definitely do, for example, is to consider $f(x)=e^n$ on $[n,n+1]$ or something similar. This is not exactly an exponential function, but "essentially".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think such a function exists. Suppose that the limit in the OP exists and is equal to $C>0$. Then using properties of limits

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\int_{1}^xf^{a}(t)dt}{(\int_{1}^x f(t)dt)^{a}}=C^a$$

We can apply L'Hopital's rule here if both integrals diverge (which they should, if we are seeking functions that are increasing and grow faster than constants) to obtain the equivalent limit- after raising to the power $1/(a-1)$ of course-

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{\int_{1}^x f(t)dt}=(aC^a)^{\frac{1}{a-1}}\equiv L$$

This limit tells us by its definition that

$$\forall ~x>x_0~,~|\frac{f(x)}{\int_1^xf(t)dt}-L|<\epsilon\Rightarrow F(x_0)e^{(L-\epsilon)(x-x_0)}<F(x)<F(x_0)e^{(L+\epsilon)(x-x_0)}$$

where the RHS has been obtained by integrating the inequality, for sufficiently small $\epsilon$, whereupon all the integrands are positive. Also $F(x)$ is the antiderivative of $f(x)$. This shows that there is not much wiggle room in the asymptotic behavior of $F(x)$ and no matter what one does for sufficiently large values, it should asymptote as an exponential. Also, if we assume as well that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$, and apply L'Hopital's rule again we can show the exact same result for f (substitute $F\rightarrow f$).